# More Idiomatic way of extracting column values and assigning it back to DF (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an existing routine that is running just fine. But since I'm new to python I find my codes to be ugly and I'm finding ways to improve it.

My program goes this way, I have created a class where it needs to have a complete address string which I need to process. Thus, this class have 4 attributes namely, address, state, city and zipcode.

This is the said class:

```py
class Address:

    def __init__(self, fulladdress):
        self.fulladdress = fulladdress.split(",")
        self.address = self.get_address()
        self.city = self.get_city()
        stateandzip = str(self.fulladdress[-1]).strip()
        self.statezip = stateandzip.split(" ")
        self.state = self.get_state()
        self.zipcode = self.get_zipcode()

    def get_address(self):
        len_address = len(self.fulladdress)
        if len_address == 3:
            return self.fulladdress[0].strip()
        elif len_address == 4:
            return self.fulladdress[0].strip() + ", " + self.fulladdress[1].strip()
        elif len_address > 5:
            temp_address = self.fulladdress[0]
            for ad in self.fulladdress[0:-3]:
                temp_address = temp_address + ", " + ad.strip()
            return temp_address
        else:
            return ''

    def get_city(self):
        if len(self.fulladdress) > 0:
            address = self.fulladdress[-2]
            return address.strip()
        else:
            return ''

    def get_state(self):
        if len(self.fulladdress) > 0:
            return self.statezip[0]
        else:
            return ''

    def get_zipcode(self):
        if len(self.fulladdress) > 0:
            return self.statezip[1]
        else:
            return ''
```

Now my existing routine needs to append this results to my dataframe which based on the address column. What I did to parse the address data is I use df.iterrows() since I don't know how can I use the Address Class using the df.apply method.

Here is the routine:

```
import pandas as pd
import datahelper as dh
import address as ad

# Find the header name of the Address column
address_header = dh.findcolumn('Address', list(df.columns))
header_loc = df.columns.get_loc(address_header)

address = []
city = []
state = []
zipcode = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if not row[address_header]:
       address.append('')
       city.append('')
       state.append('')
       zipcode.append('')
       continue

       # extract details from the address
       address_data = ad.Address(row[address_header])

       address.append(address_data.address)
       city.append(address_data.city)
       state.append(address_data.state)
       zipcode.append(address_data.zipcode)

df[address_header] = address
df.insert(header_loc + 1, 'City', city)
df.insert(header_loc + 2, 'State', state)
df.insert(header_loc + 3, 'Zip Code', zipcode)
```

I would really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction. Thank you in advance.

By the way, dh is a datahelper module where I put all my helper functions.

```
def findcolumn(searchstring, list):
    if searchstring in list:
        return searchstring
    else:
        try:
            return [i for i in list if searchstring in i][0]
        except ValueError:
            return None
        except IndexError:
            return None
```

And here is my desired output given the sample data from Address column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Address': ['Rubin Center Dr Ste, Fort Mill, SC 29708', 'Miami, FL 33169']})
```

Output should be:

```
Address             | City    | State | Zip Code
--------------------------------------------------
Rubin Center Dr Ste |Fort Mill|  SC   |29708
--------------------------------------------------
                    |Miami    | FL    |33169
```

Comment: In the routine as you call it, what does dh denote ?

Comment: Hi @Parfait, I now updated the question as stated. Thanks.